# calling include from an included file

Tags: php, include-path

So,
examining this directory structure

- */include_one.php*
- */include_two.php*
- */directory/main_file.php*

Assume that I am in */directory/main_file.php* and I call `include('../include_one.php');` inside of *include_one.php*, to include *include_two.php*. Do I need to call `include('include_two.php);` or `include('../include_two.php');`?

So my question is: When including a file, is the 'relative include path' shifted to the included file, or does it remain at the main including file?

I am aware that the best alternative would be to have a config.php which contains the root_path, however this is not possible at this stage.

---

**update:** 
So, im not sure who is right, as here is my test

directory structure

/include.php
/start/start.php
/folder1/includeone.php
/folder1/folder2/includetwo.php

and here is the contents of each file

**start.php**

```
<?php 
  echo 'including ../include.php<br />';
  include('../include.php');
?>
```

**include.php**

```
<?php 
  echo 'including folder1/includeone.php<br />';
  include('folder1/includeone.php');
?>
```

**includeone.php**

```
<?php 
  echo 'including folder2/includetwo.php<br />';
  include('folder2/includetwo.php');
?>
```

**includetwo.php**

```
<?php 
  echo 'done<br />';
?>
```

and the output is

> including ../include.php
>   including folder1/includeone.php
>   including folder2/includetwo.php
>   done

Comment: still no answer to my update...

Comment: Hi. I believe this to depend on the system running the code. I am currently working in a 4 years-old project, which is run across different OS and settings. Somehow, everytime I clone the code, I have to configure everything again, while a coworker of mine can simply run it everytime he clones it to his machine. I'm currently in search for a way to make PHP shift the "relative include path" everytime it changes from file to file.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The "relative include path" is not shifted to the included file... Which means that using relative paths generally ends badly.

A better solution, that I use almost all the time, is to always work with absolute paths -- and you can mix relatives and absolute paths using `__DIR__`, to get the directory that contains the file where this is written.

For example, in `include_one.php`, you'd use :

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/include_two.php';
```

To include the `include_two.php` file that's in the same directory as `include_one.php`.

And, in `main_file.php`, you'd use :

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../include_one.php';
```

To include the `include_one.php` file that's one directory up.

With that, your includes will work, no matter from which file they are called.

Comment: To save some space, `__DIR__` is equivalent to `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Answer (score 3):

The include path is relative to the first file in the include chain.

A good way to ensure the correct include path is to always include from the document root.

This is done like this:

`include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/folder1/folder2/includetwo.php';`

Answer (score 2):

## Two demos of how include works in PHP

Im 2010 the author has wrote in his question:

> So, im not sure who is right, as here is my test ...

and also in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334046/calling-include-from-an-included-file#comment3461012_3334046):

> still no answer to my update...

So I suggest my tests to understand how PHP includes work. The results were the same for versions 5 and 7.

### Test 1

Files and directories:

1. `/index.php`

```php
    <?php
    include 'subdirectory/index.php';
```

2. `/subdirectory/index.php`

```php
    <?php
    include 'test.php';
```

3. `/subdirectory/test.php`

```php
    <?php
    echo __FILE__;
```

The output:

> /subdirectory/test.php

This test work well, because there is **one and only one candidate** for every include.

This requirement is also met for the test from the updated question. This is why it works well too.

### Test 2

Let's copy `test.php` to the main root. So the new project structure is as follows:

```
/index.php
/test.php
/subdirectory/index.php
/subdirectory/test.php
```

Now the output becomes different::

> /test.php

Second test has another result, because there are two candidates for the instruction `include 'test.php';` and **PHP chose by itself** which file to include.

This is why the practice suggested by the author of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3334060/6263942) saves the project from surprises.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this code:

```
if(!isset($TO_HOME_DIR)) $TO_HOME_DIR="../";
```

And I include a file:

```
include_once($TO_HOME_DIR."common/include_one.php");
```

With `if(!isset($TO_HOME_DIR))`, it's not important how much you include a file into included file into included file into includ..... Only first file's -and main file's- $TO_HOME_DIR declaration is used.

Second advantage of this approach is, if you change directory of file, you only need to change one line of code; $TO_HOME_DIR declaration. :)