# Fatal error: Class not found even though file is included which contains the class

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm just trying to run a website on my local which I copied from server. 
In my `config.php`:

```
define ( 'DB_SERVER', '127.0.0.1' );
define ( 'DB_USERNAME', 'user' );
define ( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password' );
define ( 'DB_DATABASE', 'database' );

class DB_Class {
    function __construct() {
        $connection = mysql_connect ( DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD ) or die ( 'Connection error -> ' . mysql_error () );
        mysql_select_db ( DB_DATABASE, $connection ) or die ( 'Database error -> ' . mysql_error () );
    }
}
```

In my `user.php`:

```
include_once 'config.php';

class User {
    // Database connect
    public function __construct() {
        $db = new DB_Class ();
    }
}
```

In my `index.php`:

```
session_start ();
include_once ('classes/user.php');
$uobj = new User ();
```

Now whenever I attempt to create an object of a class `User` it returns a `Fatal error: Class 'DB_Class' not found` on the line where I attempt, in this case it's line 6. Though it works perfectly fine on server.

I tried to extend the class `User` to the class `DB_Class` but then again the same error on the line where I attempt to extend.

Someone please point out what's wrong. Thanks.

Comment: do you include the user.php wherever you instantiate the User object? (outside user.php file)

Comment: Yes indeed and my guess is User object creates successfully but I think problem is somewhere in user.php where it creates DB_class object. Maybe some permission error. Sorry I don't know much about it.

Comment: try $db = new \DB_Class ();

Comment: What happens if you use `require_once` rather than `include_once`?

Comment: @Aris I tried but same error.

Comment: Is your local system a Linux ?

Comment: @mattgibson I tried that too. The same.

Comment: Do a command line lint check `php -l <filename>` on your config.php.

Comment: Well, I've just pasted your exact code into two files with those names, and it works fine, with no compilation errors. What's in the code you're not showing us?

Comment: I did the same as @MattGibson and the code works fine.. can you show the code where you instantiate the User class..

Comment: @mattgibson I've added the code where I create an object of a class 'User'

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `include_once 'config.php';` in your user.php file will use the path relative to your index.php file.  It's been a while, but I generally use full paths when it comes to includes within includes.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334046/calling-include-from-an-included-file

Comment: @Robbert Include problems were why I suggested using `require_once` instead for diagnosis—a `require_once` on a file that can't be found is a fatal error, so it should have changed the result.

Comment: @AlexisPeters No I'm running in XAMPP environment on windows.

Comment: @Robbert I tried using full URL and the answer I got for the error I got is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285503/warning-require-once-http-wrapper-is-disabled-in-the-server-configuration. Now I'm confused which one to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your site structure is set up with the two class files in a folder called classes.   As this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334046/calling-include-from-an-included-file) suggests, relative paths in includes rarely go well because it's the calling script's path that is used for all includes, including those within other include files.  Unless you have specified the classes folder as in your path, index.php won't know where the config.php file is.  You should do this in your user.php file.

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/classes/config.php';
```

Or use

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php';
```

Either one will remove the relative link and allow the file to be included anywhere within your directory structure.

Comment: One thing I'm still confused about that if php couldn't find my file in my relative path, why it wasn't giving any error? Any idea?

Comment: Here also you may use [directory_separator constant](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) to make your application compatible with both windows and linux

Comment: include throws only warnings so if don't have that level of error reporting enabled, you won't see it.  Require will throw a fatal error, however.