# PHP - Include within Include not working

Tags: php

I have the following directory structure:

**home/admin/super/**

In **home** I have a file called `config.php`

```
<?php
//Get relative path - for PHP files
$documentRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mwo2015/';
include($documentRoot.'library/constants.php');
echo $paypalID;
?>
```

and `echo $paypalID` is echoed;

In path **home/admin/** I have a file called `access-control.php`

```
<?php
//Common files
include('../config.php');
?>
```

and echo `$paypalID` is echoed again.

In path **home/admin/super/** I have a file called `output.php`

```
<?php
include('../access-control.php');
?>
```

Nothing is output and I get the following error in my error_log of path

```
PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '../config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/share/pear')
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334046/calling-include-from-an-included-file

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

The "relative include path" is not shifted to the included file

The solution is work with absolute paths and  you can combine with relatives and absolute paths using `dirname(__FILE__)`, and you get the directory that contains the file.

In within include file you can use following

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/yourfile.php';
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/yourfile.php';
```

or

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . "/yourfile.php";
include dirname(__DIR__) . "/yourfile.php";
```

Comment: For PHP 5.3+, you can use `__DIR__` as well

Answer (score 0):

The problem your having is this:

Relative paths use the entry point. So if you start and go to home/admin/super/output.php you start from there.

so home/admin/super.

```
include('../access-control.php');
```

goes to home/admin

The include in this file goes to home/admin but it should go to home so to fix this you could do:

```
../../config.php
```

This is the reason why you build your application around one entry point or make a global root and webroot to use throughout your application.